# Minecraft split screen with xbox live

Tags: xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm having trouble getting 3 players on Minecraft. One player is connecting via Xbox live and 2 players are using the split screen but it will not let me connect the second player even before the second player going via Xbox live gets on.

Comment: Which account are they using? Is it a live account?

Comment: Yeah definitely check if both are live accounts,  but it also might be your monitor. I used to have a really old TV that didn't let me do split-screen because of poor graphics

Answer (score 0):

If the second player is using an account without a current Xbox LIVE Gold membership, they won't be able to play online, or join a world with the 'online' status.